GitHub Actions Workflow Authenticates with Azure but code can not access Default Credentials (any of them)
I setup Federated credentials in Azure, followed documentation to a tee. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/github/connect-from-azure-openid-connect
I can run the login commands and get success in my pipeline as below.

The issue is when I get to the build step in the pipeline and it runs my Next js code, it can not get any of the credentials from the default credentials object. I am really confused about this because I just authenticated successfully in the workflow (I checked it was successful). But it does not seem to carry through to code. I have done lots of googling but not seeing lots of similar issues, perhaps I am not phrasing it correctly.
Another picture here

Here is all the pipeline:
name: Azure Static Web Apps CI/CD

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - master
  pull_request:
    types: [opened, synchronize, reopened, closed]
    branches:
      - master
env:
    KeyVaultName: 'REDACTED'

permissions:
  id-token: write
  contents: read
jobs:
  build_and_deploy_job:
    if: github.event_name == 'push' || (github.event_name == 'pull_request' && github.event.action != 'closed')
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    environment: production
    name: Build and Deploy Job    
    
    steps:    
    - name: Azure CLI Login
      uses: azure/login@v2
      with:
        client-id: ${{ secrets.AZURE_CLIENT_ID }}
        tenant-id: ${{ secrets.AZURE_TENANT_ID }}
        subscription-id: ${{ secrets.AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION_ID }}
    
    - name: Azure CLI script
      uses: azure/cli@v2
      with:
        azcliversion: latest
        inlineScript: |
          az account set --subscription ${{ secrets.AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION_ID }}
          az account show
      
    - name: Azure PowerShell script
      uses: azure/powershell@v2
      with:
        azPSVersion: latest
        inlineScript: |
          Get-AzContext  
          # You can write your Azure PowerShell inline scripts here.
    
    - name: checkout
      uses: actions/checkout@v3
      with:
        submodules: true
        lfs: false
       # publish-profile: ${{ secrets.AZURE_FUNCTIONAPP_PUBLISH_PROFILE }}          
    
    - name: Build And Deploy
      id: builddeploy
      uses: Azure/static-web-apps-deploy@v1
      env:
        Temp_BlogPostCRUD_FunctionKeyValue: ${{ secrets.TEMP_BLOGPOSTCRUD_FUNCTIONKEYVALUE }}
      with:
        azure_static_web_apps_api_token: ${{ secrets.AZURE_STATIC_WEB_APPS_API_TOKEN_JOLLY_POND_0F0DF3810 }}
        repo_token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }} # Used for Github integrations (i.e. PR comments)
        # publish-profile: ${{ secrets.AZURE_FUNCTIONAPP_PUBLISH_PROFILE }}
        action: "upload"
        ###### Repository/Build Configurations - These values can be configured to match your app requirements. ######
        # For more information regarding Static Web App workflow configurations, please visit: https://aka.ms/swaworkflowconfig
        app_location: "/" # App source code path
        api_location: "" # Api source code path - optional
        output_location: "" # Built app content directory - optional
        ###### End of Repository/Build Configurations ######

  close_pull_request_job:
    if: github.event_name == 'pull_request' && github.event.action == 'closed'
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    name: Close Pull Request Job
    steps:
      - name: Close Pull Request
        id: closepullrequest
        uses: Azure/static-web-apps-deploy@v1
        with:
          azure_static_web_apps_api_token: ${{ secrets.AZURE_STATIC_WEB_APPS_API_TOKEN_JOLLY_POND_0F0DF3810 }}
          action: "close"


The error is below, it just can't find any credentials when looks with Azure default Credential.

Any help is appreciated, I have spent lots of time on this (days).
I tried OIDC tutorial and was able to login to Azure fine but can't find any credentials when I run my code, I was expecting code to have access to Azure resources since I logged in the Workflow file and GitHub action.

Your logs shows ChainedTokenCredential authentication failed and CredentialUnavailableError, which indicates issues with Azure credentials and Error messages like Azure CLI could not be found and Unable to execute PowerShell says that the environment is missing necessary tools.

you need to set up the GitHub Actions workflow correctly, including the steps to authenticate with Azure and deploy a static site.

Go to GitHub repository. Navigate to Settings > Secrets and variables > Actions.

Add a new secret with the name AZURE_CREDENTIALS. This secret should contain the JSON output from the az ad sp create-for-rbac command.



Please check the below updated workflow and refer this document for more understanding.
Workflow:
name: Azure Static Web Apps CI/CD

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - master
  pull_request:
    types: [opened, synchronize, reopened, closed]
    branches:
      - master

permissions:
  id-token: write
  contents: read

jobs:
  build_and_deploy_job:
    if: github.event_name == 'push' || (github.event_name == 'pull_request' && github.event.action != 'closed')
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    environment: production
    name: Build and Deploy Job    

    steps:    
    - name: Checkout repository
      uses: actions/checkout@v3
      with:
        submodules: true
        lfs: false

    - name: Azure CLI Login
      uses: azure/login@v2
      with:
        client-id: ${{ secrets.AZURE_CLIENT_ID }}
        tenant-id: ${{ secrets.AZURE_TENANT_ID }}
        subscription-id: ${{ secrets.AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION_ID }}

    - name: Run Azure CLI commands
      uses: azure/CLI@v2
      with:
        azcliversion: latest
        inlineScript: |
          az account set --subscription ${{ secrets.AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION_ID }}
          az account show
      
    - name: Run Azure PowerShell commands
      uses: azure/powershell@v2
      with:
        azPSVersion: latest
        inlineScript: |
          Get-AzContext  
          # Add your Azure PowerShell commands here
    
    - name: Build And Deploy Static Web App
      id: builddeploy
      uses: Azure/static-web-apps-deploy@v1
      with:
        azure_static_web_apps_api_token: ${{ secrets.AZURE_STATIC_WEB_APPS_API_TOKEN_JOLLY_POND_0F0DF3810 }}
        repo_token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }} # Used for Github integrations (i.e. PR comments)
        action: "upload"
        ###### Repository/Build Configurations ######
        app_location: "/" # App source code path
        api_location: "" # Api source code path - optional
        output_location: "" # Built app content directory - optional
        ###### End of Repository/Build Configurations ######

  close_pull_request_job:
    if: github.event_name == 'pull_request' && github.event.action == 'closed'
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    name: Close Pull Request Job
    steps:
      - name: Close Pull Request
        uses: Azure/static-web-apps-deploy@v1
        with:
          azure_static_web_apps_api_token: ${{ secrets.AZURE_STATIC_WEB_APPS_API_TOKEN_JOLLY_POND_0F0DF3810 }}
          action: "close"

Build and Deployment:

Note: To access Azure resources securely from GitHub Actions, you typically need to provide explicit credentials. Default credentials are not used automatically because GitHub Actions runs in a secure, isolated environment. You need to provide credentials in a secure way to authenticate your workflow to Azure.
